# PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "INTO"

Tags: java, postgresql

I am trying to execute this query `INSERT INTO tpch1g.lineitem_order_30 (SELECT * FROM tpch1g.lineitem_order WHERE number IN('1','2','4'));` in java, to run in a PostgreSQL database.
I'm getting this error: `PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "INTO"`
This is my code:

```
String sqlFileInsert= "INSERT INTO " + "\""+tableName + "_order_" + sampleSize+ "\"" + " (SELECT * FROM " + tableName + "_order WHERE number IN('1', '2', '4'));";

 try {
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
 } catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 try {
  stmt.executeUpdate(sqlFileInsert);
 } catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

The value of `sqlFileInsert` is: `INSERT INTO tpch1g.lineitem_order_30 (SELECT * FROM tpch1g.lineitem_order WHERE number IN('1','2','4'));`

Comment: Did you try to debug or at least print the value of `sqlFileInsert`?

Comment: @m0skit0 yes, the value of `sqlFileInsert` is this: `INSERT INTO "tpch1g.lineitem_order_30" (SELECT * FROM tpch1g.lineitem_order WHERE number IN('1', '2', '4'));`

Comment: And what do you think about that string in comparison to the one you posted?

Comment: @m0skit0 The string is the same and if I put it in PostgreSQL it inserts it. Through jdbc it gives this error ...

Comment: The string is the same? I don't see it to be the same, look closer.

Comment: @m0skit0 It only changes "" the table name, I already tried to remove the "", but it does not work either